# How to fix `str is undefined` nft dapp upload picture problem?

Tags: web3js, hardhat, nft, mint

I'm trying to do an example in a tutorial, I tried to run this, but I get an error that "Upload errorTypeError: str is undefined". How can I solve this?

I tried: -> deleting artifacts and then deploying with hardhat again but nothing happened and I got the same error. -> I tried to upload small pictures but nothing happened again.

Now I want to ask how can I add liquidity and a treasury process? Do you have any documents or videos about that?

[image]

Here is the project link: https://github.com/kayhannkaya/Nft-Mint-Tutorial/tree/main

SellNFT.js code:

```js
     var file = e.target.files[0];
    //check for file extension
    try {
        //upload the file to IPFS
        disableButton();
        updateMessage("Uploading image.. please dont click anything!")
        const response = await uploadFileToIPFS(file);
        if(response.success === true) {
            enableButton();
            updateMessage("")
            console.log("Uploaded image to Pinata: ", response.pinataURL)
            setFileURL(response.pinataURL);
        }
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log("Error during file upload", e);
    }
}

//This function uploads the metadata to IPFS
async function uploadMetadataToIPFS() {
    const {name, description, price} = formParams;
    //Make sure that none of the fields are empty
    if( !name || !description || !price || !fileURL)
    {
        updateMessage("Please fill all the fields!")
        return -1;
    }

    const nftJSON = {
        name, description, price, image: fileURL
    }

    try {
        //upload the metadata JSON to IPFS
        const response = await uploadJSONToIPFS(nftJSON);
        if(response.success === true){
            console.log("Uploaded JSON to Pinata: ", response)
            return response.pinataURL;
        }
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log("error uploading JSON metadata:", e)
    }
}

    data.append('pinataOptions', pinataOptions);

return axios 
    .post(url, data, {
        maxBodyLength: 'Infinity',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${JWT}`,
            'pinata_api_key': key,
            'pinata_secret_api_key': secret,
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log("image uploaded", response.data.IpfsHash)
        return {
           success: true,
           pinataURL: "https://blush-defeated-roundworm-642.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/" + response.data.IpfsHash
       };
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return {
            success: false,
            message: error.message,
        }

});
```